# type parameter in traits to define data types in scala

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and want to create a model class for a message .Message are comprisedoing of tag as key with value and value can be a string with specified length,int or a enumeration

```
tag     value
100      a    
200      b      constraint of length =45
300      0,1,2
```

where 0-new
        1-amend
        2- cancel

```
 trait ElementType  {
    type A
    type length
}


    case class Tag() extends ElementType {
      override type A = this.type

     }

  case class Value() extends ElementType{
     override type A = this.type
     override type length = this.type
    }

case class Message(
     messageId:MessageId
  )

case class MessageId(tag: Tag[Int], value: Value[String]){
  override def toString = tag + "=" + value + 1.toChar
 }
```

I am getting compile error in MessageId,is there a better way to write the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your problem with `MessageId` that it refers to a `Tag[Int]` and `Value[String]`, which have no generic parameters.

Try something like this, though I think you will need to redefine the `Tag` and `Value` classes too:

```
case class MessageId(tag: Tag{type A = Int}, value: Value{type A = String}){
  override def toString = tag + "=" + value + 1.toChar
}
```

As you seem to want to use them as generics, I would try something like this:

```
sealed trait ElementType[+A] {
    def length: Int
}

sealed trait Tag extends ElementType[Int] {
    override def length: Int = 0
}
case object Tag100 extends Tag
case object Tag200 extends Tag
case object Tag300 extends Tag

sealed trait Value[+A] extends ElementType[A] {
    override def length: Int = 0
}

final case class Value100(a: String) extends Value[String] {
    override def length: Int = a.length
}
final case class Value200(b: String) extends Value[String] {
    require(b.length <= length)
    override def length: Int = 45
}
case object Value300One extends Value[Nothing]
case object Value300Two extends Value[Nothing]
case object Value300Three extends Value[Nothing]

case class Message(
    messageId:MessageId
)

case class MessageId(tag: Tag, value: Value[String]){
    override def toString = tag + "=" + value + 1.toChar
}
```

`+` in `[+A]` means the type will be covariant, so if `Q` is a subtype of `R`, `ElementType[Q]` is a subtype of `ElementType[R]`. (This is necessary for `Tag` to be compatible with any `ElementType` (so it extends the extreme `ElementType[Nothing]`).)

Your use case for `length` is not clear for me. If you want it to be a compiletime constraint, take alook at Shapeless' [Sized](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/shapeless-2.3.2/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/sized.scala) and [an example](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#collections-with-statically-known-sizes) on its usage.

Comment: Can u explain the code a bit I am new to scala, +A means here.The element can be a enumeration also .how will I be setting up the length of element

Comment: Length is basically the constraint

Comment: @coder25 I have updated the new code with some explanation. (To be honest, I do not understand your first paragraph either.)

Comment: Tag will always be a integer type.still not clear with usage of [+A].I want to set the length of the value with the given length.every field  may have a different length

Comment: Messages is comprised of field  with tag as key and Value as value.tag are ints and value can be a string with length constraint or a enumeration.

Comment: Updated once again, though still not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want type level constriaints on length? In that case seriously check Shapeless' Sized. Otherwise probably this is closer to your use case.

Comment: sealed trait Tag extends Tag[Int] ,i think i should be sealed trait Tag extends ElementType[Int]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151157/discussion-between-coder25-and-gabor-bakos).