# Possible ways to pass argument of different type to case class

Tags: scala, case-class

I want to group elements of different types  into one.

Following is one example

```
trait Element

case class ElementString(key:String,value:String) extends Element
case class ElementDouble(key:String,value:Double) extends Element
case class ElementInt(key:String,value:Int) extends Element

Grp(ElementString("2","abc"),ElementDouble("3",100.20),ElementInt("4",10))
```

- One possible way is to use varargs `case class Grp(group:Element*)`.

  Is there any other efficient way to achieve the above .
  Any possible way to add elements one by one into Grp

**Updated**

I would also like to create a Group inside a Group.

Comment: What do you mean by 'efficient'?

Comment: @NimrodArgov probably Possible ways is right word.I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DSL like this is very common in scala because it is type-safe, but also very concise to use:

```
trait Value

object Value {
  case class StringValue(value: String) extends Value
  case class DoubleValue(value: Double) extends Value
  case class IntValue(value: Int) extends Value
}

case class Element(key: String, value: Value)
object Element {
  implicit def fromStringPair (a: (String,String)) = Element(a._1, Value.StringValue(a._2))
  implicit def fromDoublePair (a: (String,Double)) = Element(a._1, Value.DoubleValue(a._2))
  implicit def fromIntPair (a: (String,Int)) = Element(a._1, Value.IntValue(a._2))
}

case class Grp (elements: Element*)

Grp(
  "2" -> "abc",
  "3" -> 100.20,
  "4" -> 10
)

//: Grp = Grp(WrappedArray(Element(2,StringValue(abc)), Element(3,DoubleValue(100.2)), Element(4,IntValue(10))))
```

Alternative, no varargs:

```
trait Value

// define these in different files if you want
case class Student(value: String) extends Value
case class Employee(value: Double) extends Value
case class Department(value: Int) extends Value

case class Element(key: String, value: Value)

case class Grp (elements: List[Element] = Nil) extends Value {
  def add (key: String, value: Value): Grp = Grp(this.elements ++ List(Element(key, value)))
}

Grp()
  .add("2", Student("abc"))
  .add("3", Employee(100.20))
  .add("4", Department(10))
  .add("5", Grp().add("2", Student("xyz"))) // nested group
```

Comment: case class Grp (elements: Element*) .any alternative to varargs.i do not want varargs

Comment: @coder25 There are many. What is your objection to varargs so I can understand what to suggest?

Comment: First is -you have defined case classes inside object mine are almost 30-60 case classes...they are complex and are in separate files.
Varargs  as I want elements to be added one by one.I do not want to use it.Can you suggest another possible way

Comment: my case classes are defined in way `case class ElementString(key:String,value:String) extends Element`.They are complex structure .I just took String Int as just paramters.You can consider like case class representing Student,Employee,department..each  with different trait

Comment: @coder25 How does the fact that they are more complex structures disqualify this approach?

Comment: Post a few of the case classes that you **actually** want to use

Comment: You have created case classes inside a object Value and mine are all in different files

Comment: something similar accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45521153/type-parameter-in-traits-to-define-data-types-in-scala

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152345/discussion-between-coder25-and-alvaro-carrasco).

Comment: Updated alternative

Comment: thanks this suits me.One more query.If u want I can update my question also.Possible way to nest the Group that is group inside a group.

Comment: `case class Grp (...) extends Value {...`

Comment: Extending value .can you explain further .I am maintaining a  a list right?Plus in DSL answer `"2" -> Student("abc")`,I think u did a typo

Comment: @coder25 Added a nested group. Not sure what you mean by "maintaining a list".

Comment: I didnt get the point when I say I have extends value in Grp class

Comment: I think u did some typo in dsl answer while creating  group.u mentioned student

Comment: No typo, just my understanding of a nested group (which may be incorrect for the domain): A group as the value of an element inside another group. But I'm not about to fully learn the domain, I'm just trying to help with the scala portion, it's up to you to take it and apply it based on the actual domain.

Comment: Your undestanding is correct.I am happy with the answer  but in dsl answer there is no student class in that part.u have mentioned student in alternative  answer.is am referring to `"2" -> Student("abc",`.

Comment: Ah sorry, I see it now, Yes, that was a typo. Corrected.

Comment: Thks.I will try the dsl part as well.last query can you explain the reason to extend `value` in  class `Grp`

Comment: Can you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812470/make-string-using-productiterator

Answer (score 0):

You can use a quasi builder pattern by adding the a function:

```
def withElement(elem: Element) = copy(group = group :+ elem)
```

Assuming group is a list. Note that this does make a new copy of the case class each time you call `withElement`. The code would then look like:

```
Grp().withElement(...).withElement(...)
```

You could create a real builder pattern if performance was important.

Comment: use mean to create a  `case class Grp(){def withElement(elem: Element) = copy(group = group :+ elem)}`.
Can you please explain copy(group = group :+ elem).Assuming group is list.As per my understanding it means a empty list inside Grp case class right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45763023/scala-create-group-of-elements which is finally i want to achieve

Comment: Yes, you would need a `group` member of the case class which is an empty list by default.

Comment: `copy` is a function you get when you create a case class (one of Scala's perks), that allows you to create a copy of the case class with some of the fields updated. In this case I'm updating the `group` list, by adding an element. Each successive call to `withElement` adds another element to the list.

Comment: The documentation of `copy` can be found [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html)

Comment: if i have 20 items to add it will create 20 copies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152343/discussion-between-nimrodargov-and-coder25).