# Possible way to iterate over case class elements

Tags: scala, case-class

This is with reference to question
[Possible ways to pass argument of different type to case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45774454/possible-ways-to-pass-argument-of-different-type-to-case-class)

```
 trait Value

// define these in different files if you want
case class Student(value: String) extends Value
case class Employee(value: Double) extends Value
case class Department(value: Int) extends Value

case class Element(key: String, value: Value)

case class Grp (elements: List[Element] = Nil) extends Value {
  def add (key: String, value: Value): Grp = Grp(this.elements ++ List(Element(key, value)))

}

Grp()
  .add("2", Student("abc"))
  .add("3", Employee(100.20))
  .add("4", Department(10))
  .add("5", Grp().add("2", Student("xyz"))) // nested group
```

I want to add a function inside a Grp class

`def addSubGroup(group: Grp):Grp=group.elements.foreach(s=>add(s))`

But since return is Unit it doesn't add elements

**Update 1**

Can anyone suggest me  solution to both of the approaches

1. I want my call to be like below.I want something like `val subgroup` which contains the subgroup and addSubGroup adds subgroup to group.

   ```
     Grp()
     .add("2", Student("abc"))
     .add("3", Employee(100.20))
     .add("4", Department(10))
     .addSubGroup("5", Grp().add("2", Student("xyz"))) // nested group
   ```

**Update 2**

2. If I use group subtype like `case class GrpA() extends Grp` and `case class GrpB() extends Grp.`But case class inheritance is prohibited
3. Any possible way to get rid of multiple add calls.

   Note:   **Please share solution without varargs if possible**

Comment: With untyped values using case class as `Product`, using macros, or libraries like Shapeless

Answer (score 1):

You can rid of multiple `add` with vararg method in the companion object like

```
def apply(elements: (String, Value)*): Grp = Grp(elements.map(Element.tupled).toList)
```

Group catenation could be implemented as usual  `++` method like

```
def ++(that: Grp) = Grp(elements ++ that.elements)
```

If you want your group to be some kind of iterable, respecting subroups, you can make it so, extending `Iterable[Element]` and implementing

```
def iterator: Iterator[Element] = elements.iterator.flatMap {
  case Element(name, sub: Grp) => sub.iterator
  case element                 => Iterator.single(element)
}
```

Full `Grp` code example:

```
case class Grp(elements: List[Element] = Nil) extends Value with Iterable[Element] {
  def add(key: String, value: Value): Grp = Grp(this.elements :+ Element(key, value))
  def ++(that: Grp) = Grp(elements ++ that.elements)
  def iterator: Iterator[Element] = elements.iterator.flatMap {
    case Element(name, sub: Grp) => sub.iterator
    case element                 => Iterator.single(element)
  }
}

object Grp {
  def apply(elements: (String, Value)*): Grp = Grp(elements.map(Element.tupled).toList)
}

val group = Grp("2" -> Student("abc"),
                "3" -> Employee(100.20)) ++
            Grp("4" -> Department(10),
                "5" -> Grp("2" -> Student("xyz"),
                           "6" -> Employee(200.3))) // nested group


group.foreach(println)
//Element(2,Student(abc))
//Element(3,Employee(100.2))
//Element(4,Department(10))
//Element(2,Student(xyz))
//Element(6,Employee(200.3))
```

#### Update A

You can still use your `add` syntax instead of tuple seq factory:

```
val group = Grp()
            .add("2", Student("abc"))
            .add("3", Employee(100.20))
            .add("4", Department(10))
            .add("5", Grp()
                      .add("2", Student("xyz"))
                      .add("6", Employee(200.3))) // nested group
```

Comment: Thks nice answer.

Comment: In case I don't want dsl and then use subgroup method with multiple add .can u suggest a way to do that

Comment: yes but i want to a subgroup method for segregation as mentioned in my question

Comment: Extending Iterable seems to break case class pretty printing

Answer (score 0):

If tweeking a little bit the types is allowed, I would use something like:

```
sealed trait Value

trait BaseValue extends Value

// define these in different files if you want
case class Student(value: String) extends BaseValue
case class Employee(value: Double) extends BaseValue
case class Department(value: Int) extends BaseValue

case class Grp(elements: List[(String, BaseValue)] = Nil,
               subGroups: List[(String, Grp)] = Nil) extends Value {
  def add(entries: (String, BaseValue)*): Grp = Grp(elements ++ entries, subGroups)
  def addSubGroup(entries: (String, Grp)*): Grp = Grp(elements, subGroups ++ entries)

}

Grp()
  .add("2" -> Student("abc"), "3" -> Employee(100.20), "4" -> Department(10)) // base elements
  .addSubGroup("5" -> Grp().add("2" ->Student("xyz"))) // nested group
```

This would result in the following:

```
res0: Grp = Grp(List((2,Student(abc)), (3,Employee(100.2)), (4,Department(10))),List((5,Grp(List((2,Student(xyz))),List()))))
```