# make string using productiterator

Tags: scala, case-class

I want to write to String representation of `case class Grp`

```
 trait Value

// define these in different files if you want
case class Student(value: String) extends Value
case class Employee(value: Double) extends Value
case class Department(value: Int) extends Value

case class Element(key: String, value: Value)

case class Grp (elements: List[Element] = Nil) extends Value {
  def add (key: String, value: Value): Grp = Grp(this.elements ++ List(Element(key, value)))

}

  val s=  Grp()
      .add("2", Student("abc"))
      .add("3", Employee(100.20))
      .add("4", Department(10))
      .add("5", Grp().add("2", Student("xyz"))) // nested group
```

I want to print key value pairs separated by "="

```
     print(s.productIterator.mkString(""))
```

Comment: Are you expecting something like this? https://scalafiddle.io/sf/2rVSIcV/0 In this fiddle `print` function is not working but it will work fine on your system.

Comment: @SahilGulati any other way to print without case match

Comment: Do you want to print it in the same way but other than using `case match`?

Comment: yes using key =value but no `case match` and `println`

Comment: a method to concatenation all values into one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
s.elements.map(elem => elem.key.toString + "=" + elem.value.toString).mkString(",")
```

This will produce an output like:

> 2=Student(abc),3=Employee(100.2),4=Department(10),5=Grp(List(Element(2,Student(xyz))))